# About the html img src

Tags: html, firefox

I have a problem for html img, if I want to show the image, I write

```html
<img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/9/97/Harry_Potter.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140603201724" />
```

it cannot display the image, but I can download the image, or new page can display, so what's wrong of my code

ps. I try to delete the cookie and also is it.

Comment: I ran your code and it's working for me.

Comment: Do you see any errors on console? or the networks tab in the developer tools?

Comment: if i use firefox, it cannot show the image, and the error is GET https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/9/97/Harry_Potter.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140603201724 [404
Not Found], but this link in chrome or Safari is work

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is correct.

Example:

```
<img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/9/97/Harry_Potter.jpg">
```

Comment: so if you try to download, it will fail

Comment: so it is any problem or error in this link? why remove after .jpg can fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the referer data being sent. Delete your cache and  add `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` so no referrer data would be sent. It seems to be working in firefox:

```html
<img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/9/97/Harry_Potter.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140603201724" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

It has to be Like This, as this is the correct location of the image.

```
<img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/9/97/Harry_Potter.jpg">
```

Comment: so if I have this link https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/grandchase/images/f/f9/%E4%BC%8A%E4%BF%84_%E8%B6%85%E8%B6%8A_%E5%9C%96%E7%A4%BA_kakao.png/revision/latest?cb=20200414194437&path-prefix=zh, how I can find the correct location?